# Rails 4 - Displaying associated attribute (without all attributes in associated table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a profile model.

Im trying to display a user's roles in that profile show page.

I have three models:

User

```
 rolify (which has a user_role join table)
```

Role

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
```

In my profile show page, I have:

```
<%= @profile.user.roles.each do |role|  %>
    <%= role.name.titlecase %> <span style= "margin-right: 30px"></span>
<% end %>
```

In the show view, I get:

```
Manager [#<Role id: 9, name: "faculty_manager", resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2016-01-16 08:06:55", updated_at: "2016-01-16 08:06:55">]
```

The 'Manager' part is the only correct part. How do I get the show page not to set out all the other attributes in the role table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<%= @profile` instead of just `<% @profile` which puts result of enumerator in the view

```
<% @profile.user.roles.each do |role|  %>
    <%= role.name.titlecase %> <span style= "margin-right: 30px"></span>
<% end %>
```

If you want to fetch `name` only for each role then do this

```
<% @profile.user.roles.pluck(:name).each do |role_name| %>
```

Comment: It's deliberate to use @ profile. It gives a name error if you do the local only: undefined local variable or method `profile'. I can see the association is working, because it is correctly retrieving the attributes of the right table - but I only want 1 of those attributes. I want to know how to exclude the other attributes.

Comment: @user2860931 it was a typo, fixed that

Comment: @user2860931 also I updated answer to fetch only the `name` field from DB

Comment: That second way didn't work - it just shows a blank space (no error). thanks though - the first way works

Answer (score 0):

To set your show page in a nice table view format do something  like the following in you show page code:

The error was using <%**=** @profile.user.roles.each do |role| %>
**Note the = you used**

```
<table class="table ld-margin-top-20">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Manager ID</th>
      <th>Manger Name</th>
      <th>Manger Resource ID</th>
      <th>Manger Resource Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @profile.user.roles.each do |role| %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= role.id %></td>
          <td> <%= role.name.titlecase %></td>
          <td><%= role.resource_id %></td>
          <td><%= role.resource_type %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: @user2860931 I have a request to you that if some answer helped you or not just acknowledge it, that improves our stackoverflow community, rather than asking questions constantly using SO and getting benefitted.

Comment: The '=' sign in the css works for me. That's a typo and now corrected, but the substance of my question isn't how to show each attribute int he role table. It's the opposite. I only want to show the 'name'. I think I am asking for 'name' ONLY, but it is giving me everything. I want to exclude the rest.

Comment: its your choice to select which all details you want to display or not, if you don't need a column just remove it from your code, that's all.

Comment: That's not really helpful given I only asked for one attribute. Thanks anyway. The other answer above solved it for me.

Comment: Choosing an answer best for you is purely depend on your choices, no problem ...! But remember in future if you want to display any associated field with manger, the code wont work for you as it only select the name associated only. bye tc.

Comment: No idea what that means. I think I've got it working in a way that I want. Thanks anyway for your effort.